# EXPRESS GET info on user

Tags: node.js, json, express, mongoose

Hello I want to be able to pass a user into a get request to see what items they have posted.

Here is the GET request

```
// @route  GET with NAME
// @desc   GET All ITEMS WITH NAME
// @access private
router.get('/:user', (req, res) => {
    Item.findBy(req.params.user)
        .sort({ date: -1})
        .then(items => res.json(items))    
});
```

Then I want to be able to pass it through the actions file.

```
export const getItems = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(setItemsLoading());
    axios.get(`/api/items/`).then(res => 
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ITEMS,
                payload: res.data
            })
            )
            .catch(err => 
                dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
            );
    }
```

Here is the item modal if anyone was wondering

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Schema
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    user:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = Item = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);
```

The expected results of this would be

http://localhost:3000/{username}

Product list
"name":"Item name"
"date": "mm/dd/yy"

I am also new to mongoDB/Json. I am coming from using SQL.

Answer (score -1):

In this case I would use `req.query.user` and the url would be `http://localhost:3000/?username`.

Then in `router.get` method pull the correct db data from mongoDB and `res.send` data to client.

Comment: ```
router.get('/:user', (req, res) => {
    try{
    const user = await.findBy(req.query.user)
    res.send(user)
    }catch(err){
        res.json({message : err})
    }
});
```
I tried this and it is not working. I just get an error message. How should I debug this?